# CSS: Button text rests at bottom of seemingly larger than defined line height

Tags: css

I've got a issue where class styles applied to an element are rendering differently depending on whether it's applied to an anchor tag or a button.

My class, 'btn' is defined below;

```
.btn {
    background:transparent;
    border:2px solid #FFF;
    padding: 18px 30px 18px;
    line-height:1.7em;
    max-width:100%;
    white-space:normal;
    margin-top:25px;
    border-radius:100px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing:0.1em;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    transition:all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
   }
```

When applied to an anchor tag, it renders as expected;

[image: a tag]

But when applied to a button, it gives the button a seemingly larger line height, where the text rests at the base;

[image: button tag]

I've tried reseting the button's line-height at the beginning of the css file but that didn't help.

Does anyone know what's going on here? How can I make the buttons and anchor tags render in the same way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body{background:#666;}

.btn {
    background:transparent;
    border:2px solid #FFF;
    padding: 18px 30px 18px;
    line-height:1.7em;
    max-width:100%;
    white-space:normal;
    margin-top:25px;
    border-radius:100px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing:0.1em;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    transition:all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
   }
```

```html
<a class="btn">Download brochure</a>

<button type="button" class="btn">Download brochure</button>
```

Seems to be working almost okay on their own - only a few pixels off?

[image]

Comment: I suppose what I was really asking is why isn't mine working like that...? What might there be in my code that's applying a greater line-height to buttons without showing up when I inspect the element?

Comment: Did you check for any extra classes applied to the button? Hard to tell without seeing the actual rendered output.

Comment: Yes, there doesn't seem to be anything else being applied to the button. You can see the webpage with both the anchor and the button here; http://group.rhinodesign.co.uk/digital/social-media-marketing/

Comment: When you expand the button's code within inspector you will see a br tag which is adding the extra line height. Please check my original answer- I've added a screenshot

Comment: Thank you! That isn't showing up in the Wordpress backend but is being applied to the rendered output, probably because I put the text on a new line by itself. Thanks once again.

Comment: No worries at all